# Edit a value in a list of dictionary

Tags: python

```
my_dicts = [ 
{ 'key1' : '1', 'key2' : '5' },
{ 'key1' : '2', 'key2' : '10' },
{ 'key1' : '3', 'key2' : '15' }]
```

What would be the most efficient way to replace

`{ 'key1' : '2', 'key2' : '10' }`

in

`{ 'key1' : '2', 'key2' : '30' }`

Comment: "most efficient way" - a wildly popular phrase used by beginners who cannot solve simple tasks. I simply don't understand where this people come from, and why are they obsessed with efficiency they don't need.

Answer (score 2):

use `enumerate` :

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(my_dicts) :
...   if j== { 'key1' : '2', 'key2' : '10' }:
...      my_dicts[i]= {'key1' : '2', 'key2' : '30' }
... 
>>> my_dicts
[{'key2': '5', 'key1': '1'}, {'key2': '30', 'key1': '2'}, {'key2': '15', 'key1': '3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The index of the list you've created can be used to update the list:

```
my_dicts[1] = { 'key1' : '2', 'key2' : '30' }

print my_dicts
```

Yielding:

```
[{'key2': '5', 'key1': '1'}, {'key2': '30', 'key1': '2'}, {'key2': '15', 'key1': '3'}]
```

If you need to do this programmatically, you'll have to locate  the index to update, but in terms of efficiency, this is it.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't say you have to loop through anything so, this:

```
my_dicts[1]['keys2'] = 30;
```